# Improve OCR results custom

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have some issues with text extraction from image using tesseract engine, can any one give me some tips to improve the accuracy as this info should be at least 99% accurate, below is the used code .

[Sample of images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD2sX.png)

```
image = cv2.imread(imgfile)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), 2)

# Remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,15))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), 3)

# Dilate to connect text and remove dots
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10,1))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Bitwise-and to reconstruct image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=dilate)
result[dilate==0] = (255,255,255)

# OCR
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, lang='eng',config='--psm 6 tessedit_char_whitelist="0123456789%."')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @HamzehAbuAjamieh - please updated your answer to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - it's not clear what your issue is - what isn't working, what have you tried / failed on?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, please embed the image in the question. Also, what does the number in the image represent?

Comment: Hi@ranka47, i am newbie to ocr, i don't know where exactly the problem is and a sample of the images is attached.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)?

If you up-sample your image two-times

[image]

Then OCR:

```
24,026
56.5%
5,798
13.6%
4,236
10.0%
3,546
8.3%
4,905
11.5%
42,511
100.0%

20,968
66.0%
9,279
29.2%
1,328
4.2%
145
0.5%
47
0.1%
31,767
100.0%

5,854
77.8%

1,617
21.5%

45
0.6%

0.1%
7,523
100.0%

50,848
62.2%
16,694
20.4%

5,564

3,736
4.6%
4,959
6.1%

81,801

100.0%

24,826
78.1%
5,866
18.5%
11
0.0%

1.6%
562
1.8%
31,773
100.0%

26,499
81.1%
5,940
18.2%
55
0.2%
167
0.5%

32,661
100.0%

6,008
87.2%

839
12.2%

0.6%

0.0%

6,886
100.0%

57,333
80.4%
12,645
17.7%

0.1%
713
1.0%

0.8%

71,320
100.0%
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("FD2sX.png")

# Up-sample
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2)

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# OCR
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(gry))
```

If your pytesseract version is not [0.3.7](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/), you might get different results.

Comment: Hi @Ahx , still facing some issues, it skips some numbers, will go through the possible ways to improve the accuracy, Thank you.

Comment: Glad if I could help